# Html5- Organization hierarchy structure drawn using SVG path getting clipped on left hand side

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I am working on creating a Organization tree hierarchy like structure(attached screenshot below) using Html5 and SVG, I wanted the structure to be aligned at the center but its getting aligned to the left due to which two branches which were aren't visible. I am missing adding any property here? so that I can draw the structure and nothing gets cropped!

Current code can be seen at : 
https://jsfiddle.net/wsLzLum5/2/

```
 ![Screenshot][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvt0S.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lowest x-coordinates in your path is -263, yet you have specified that your view box only extends from 0 to 615 in this dimension.

Either extend your viewbox:

`<svg version="1.1" viewbox="-300 0 615 455" style="width: 615px; height: 600px;">`

or modify the path coordinates such that they are all within the 0-615 range.

Comment: Thank you. Along with the changes to viewbox coordinate, I have changed the width to 1000px, now its working fine! Any pointers on how to create the widget like structure which are present at the end of the lines(as shown in screenshot)? Only CSS be used to achieve it?

Comment: I don't think I'd try to do those shapes with css. Couldn't you just use a `<rect>` with rounded corners for the box and a couple of `<line>`s to make the triangular bit?